# Reliable thread-safe map

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, discord

I was making a `WaitForResponse` function for my Discord bot, and it works, but the user can still use commands even when the bot is expecting a response. I combated this by using a map with the user and channel IDs, but I was then hit with the dreaded `fatal error: concurrent map read and write`. So I tried using a `sync.Map`, however it wouldn't always work when I spammed the command. I could sometimes still run commands when the bot was expecting a response. Is there any way I can ensure that the values are getting added and removed from the map when and as they should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these scenarios, [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) can be used to ensure that only one modification is allowed by acquiring a *lock* around the code that you want to be thread-safe.

```golang
var mu sync.Mutex

func readMap(key string) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    return yourMap[key]
}

func updateMap(key, value string) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    yourMap[key] = value
}
```

Mutex ensures that *ONLY ONE* goroutine can is allowed access to the *locked* code, which means for your case, only one operation, either read or write can be performed.

For better efficiency, you should consider using [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) since you might not want to lock the map when it's being read. From GoDoc:

> A RWMutex is a reader/writer mutual exclusion lock. The lock can be held by an arbitrary number of readers or a single writer. The zero value for a RWMutex is an unlocked mutex.

```golang
var mu sync.RWMutex

func readMap(key string) {
    mu.RLock()
    defer mu.RUnlock()

    return yourMap[key]
}

func updateMap(key, value string) {
    mu.Lock()
    defer mu.Unlock()

    yourMap[key] = value
}
```